# sql sum for two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum

**I need help with some basic sql...** 
here is the problem:
In first table I have

```
ID (primary key) 
data column (varchar)
```

which contains products, in other I have

```
ID (primary) 
second ID (foreign key) //references to ID from first table
price (decimal 8,2)
```

What I need is to SUM price from second table that corresponds products from first table. also it should be saved as view.
*any help?*

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: I will now give it a try... :) Hope it will work...

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` the two tables, with `GROUP BY` and an aggregate function `SUM` like this:

```
CREATE VIEW DataPrices
AS
    SELECT 
      p.id,
      p.data,
      SUM(t.price) 
    FROM products p
    INNER JOIN secondtable t ON p.ID = t.ForeignKeyToTable1
    GROUP BY p.Id, p.data;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select table1.id, table1.data, sum(table2.price) as `total`
from   table1 inner join table2  
         on table1.id = table2.foreignkeyId
group  by table1.id, table1.data
```

Comment: brackets are not allowed in mysql unless you have wrap it with backticks.

Comment: create view vSuma1
as
select klaseosiguranja.id_klaseosiguranja, klaseosiguranja.nazivklase, sum(odsete.odsteta) as 'total'
from klaseosiguranja inner join odsete
    on klaseosiguranja.id_klaseosiguranja = odsete.id_klaseosiguranja
group by klaseosiguranja.id_klaseosiguranja, klaseosiguranja.nazivklase;

so here is the code, it wont work, error is 'total' token unknown